# Cite a Data Source in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am creating two simples bar graphs in matplotlib and I need to cite where I got the data from. Is there a function that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.annotate()`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) to cite your source at the foot of your plot. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.annotate('[your citation here]', (0,0), (-80,-20), fontsize=6, 
             xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', va='top')
```